# How to convert Base64 encoded string to bitmapData in flash as2?

Tags: flash, image, decode, encode, actionscript-2

I have converted a jpg image to Base64 string and saved somewhere.

**Now**

How can i convert this Base64 encoded string to bitmapData in flash as2?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/ library to convert byte array and than load it.

```
private function loadImage(byteArrayData:String) {
            var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
            data = by.blooddy.crypto.Base64.decode( byteArrayData );
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showImage);
            loader.loadBytes(data);

        }

        private function showImage(e:Event):void {
            var src:BitmapData = new BitmapData(e.target.content.width, e.target.content.height);
            src.draw(e.target.content);
            var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(src);
            addChild(bmp);
        }
```